# Licencing of Custom Extensions

Tags: extensions, gpl

The answer to this is probably on the joomla site but I can't find it.

The business model for my company is Software as a Service (SaaS).  I am using joomla.

If I write an extension for joomla am I legally required to publish it?

Obviously joomla is very much an open source philosophy, but I find it hard to believe anyone would have a use for any extension written by myself.  There is also the issue of loss of revenue if I open up my software (which is basically an expert system) to be copied to a third party's site.

Comment: No, you're not required to publish the software. You can use it privately.